# ShowDialog is not displaying on Button Click event in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to display a dialog popup whenever the user clicks on a button. However, whenever I test this the dialog not displayed and an exception has been thrown in Chrome console.

Exception message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')
    at Object.a9 (main.dart.js:16645)
    at Object.DV (main.dart.js:4402)
    at main.dart.js:65305
    at b7F.a (main.dart.js:20524)
    at b7F.$2 (main.dart.js:49122)
    at Object.l (main.dart.js:20510)
    at aUl.$0 (main.dart.js:65307)
    at NQ.YO (main.dart.js:80893)
    at Object.eval (eval at bio (main.dart.js:13895), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at je.a5X (main.dart.js:76162)
```

and here's my dart code:

```
ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () async {
          showDialog(context: context, builder: (_){
               return const AlertDialog(title: Text("Test"),);
          });
     },
     child: const Text("Test")
)
```

I tried to put `await` before `showDialog` but still the problem persists.

Comment: Can you include parent widget

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to declare Alert

1.By create separate method/function

```
showMyDialog() async {
  return showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, 
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('AlertDialog Title'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: const <Widget>[
              Text('This is a demo alert dialog.'),
              Text('Would you like to approve of this message?'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: const Text('Approve'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Your Widget:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    showMyDialog();
  },
  child: const Text(
    "Pressed Me",
  ),
),
```

Your result Screen-> [image]

2. By declare `OnPressed` function

   ```
     ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => showDialog<String>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text(
            'AlertDialog Title',
          ),
          content: const Text(
            'AlertDialog description',
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
                context,
                'Cancel',
              ),
              child: const Text('Cancel'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(
                context,
                'OK',
              ),
              child: const Text(
                'OK',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: const Text(
        'Pressed Me',
      ),
    ),
   ```

Your result screen-> [image]

Refer Documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html)

You Can refer my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70530116/13997210) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70002958/13997210) also for `AlertDialog`

If you dismiss your alert automatically refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70125175/13997210)

Test Both solution [here](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the solutions you mentioned worked. The dialog just doesn't show up in the web version of flutter for some reason.

Comment: Both code are run on my machine, are you get any error or warning?

Comment: The error I get is the one that I see in the chrome console which you can read above in my question.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what was the issue, on my main MaterialApp definition, I used the `builder` instead of `home` or `route`. And that caused the issue. However, when I switched to using `home` instead, it worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Even the solution mentioned on [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/95987) github thread didn't work for me. The only solution was resorting to [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_smart_dialog) package that works well on all platforms.